# Remove white space from string elements

Tags: php, regex

I've a string which at run time I explode into separate elements (tags). these are inputted via a text field.

I want to remove excess white space before and after the `,`.

Here is the string example:

```
$str = "tags,more tags  ,even more tags,     great art, painting, clay,shoes,cows,big cows,   big big cows";
```

I ran

```
$str = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/',' ', $str));
```

However it returns:

```
tags,more tags ,even more tags, great art, painting, clay,shoes,cows,big cows, big big cows"
```

Still has white space surrounding the `,`.

Any suggestions?

Thanks for responses. I since tried this which also worked:

```
$str = implode(',', array_map('trim',explode(',' , $str)));
```

Comment: so this is using jquery is it?

Comment: preg_replace is a PHP function I believe.

Comment: No jquery - straight forward form input and post n process

Comment: Please learn how to format your code.

Comment: Please be more specific, can't learn/change if you don't know what is wrong with it. New here so no sure of exact protocol and formatting requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
$str = "tags,more tags ,even more tags, great art, painting, clay,shoes,cows";
$str = trim(preg_replace('/[ ]*,[ ]*/',',', $str));
echo $str;
//Output: tags,more tags,even more tags,great art,painting,clay,shoes,cows
```